# Create pair RDDs from list of characters

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm trying to create a paired RDD where the keys will come from an RDD and the values will all be 1.

So for example, if someone were to import the string `"hello world!"` and parallelize it into an RDD, the output would be: `('h', 1), ('e', 1), ('l', 1), ('l', 1),...`

So far, I've written:

```
keyRDD = characterRDD.map(lambda x: (x, 1))
```

which results in an output of `(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd,' '!'], 1)`. Close, but not what I'm looking for.

I've also tried using a for loop, but received an error for trying to iterate over an RDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` with list comprehension:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(["hello world!"])

rdd = rdd.flatMap(lambda s: [(l, 1) for l in s if l != ' '])

print(rdd.collect())
#[('h', 1), ('e', 1), ('l', 1), ('l', 1), ('o', 1), ('w', 1), ('o', 1), ('r', 1), ('l', 1), ('d', 1), ('!', 1)]
```